# Python - comparing sets and returning the one with the most matching elements

Tags: python, set

I have a set of Strings: `{'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'}` for instance, I'll call it `x`. The set can have up to 10 strings.

There is also a big list of sets, for instance `[{'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'}, {'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'}, {'Type B', 'Type C, 'Type D'}, {'Type E', 'Type F', 'Type G'}]` and so on.

My goal is to return all the sets in the big list that contain 60% or more of the same elements as `x`. So in this example, it would return the first 3 sets but not the 4th.

I know I could iterate over every set, compare elements, and then use the number of similarities to go about my business, but this is quite time intensive and my big list will probably have many many sets. Is there a better way to go about this? I thought about using `frozenset()` and hashing them, but I'm not sure what hashing function I would use, and how I would compare hashes.

Any help would be appreciated - many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "compare the elements"?  Couldn't you just get the `intersection` of 2 sets & check the size?

Comment: @ScottHunter oh, thank you! I forgot about intersections - I think that should solve my problem,

Comment: `set` elements are already hashed, so finding an element is an `O(1)` operation. That being said, your main overhead is to iterate over the list since it is supposed to have _many many sets_ and hashing won't help with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = [{'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'}, {'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'}, {'Type B', 'Type C', 'Type D'}, {'Type E', 'Type F', 'Type G'}]

x = {'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'}

for s in l:
    print (len(x.intersection(s)))
```

Output:

```
3
3
2
0
```

With a function and a list of tuples returned:

```
def more_than(l,n):
    return [ (s,round(len(x.intersection(s))/len(x),2)) for s in l if len(x.intersection(s))/len(x) > n]
 
print (more_than(l,0.6))
```

Output:

```
[({'Type B', 'Type A', 'Type C'}, 1.0), ({'Type B', 'Type A', 'Type C'}, 1.0), ({'Type B', 'Type C', 'Type D'}, 0.67)]
```

Here, just for convenience, I used `round(len(x.intersection(s))/len(x),2)` which translates to `round(x,y)`. The `round()` will simply round your ratio to the number of decimal mentioned using the `y` variable.

Comment: Note that this will only print the sets but it won't return them in a list as required by the OP. It also doesn't check for the threshold (60%).

Comment: Check the edit, the first was only the principle

Comment: @Synthase, could you please help me to figure out why you used 2 in this tupple. (s,round(len(x.intersection(s))/len(x),2)). I am a beginner for python and learning from others problems and through the given answers.

Comment: @Synthase, I would definetly tick the accept button, but this question was raised by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
x = {'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'}
lst = [{'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'}, 
       {'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type C'}, 
       {'Type B', 'Type C', 'Type D'},
       {'Type E', 'Type F', 'Type G'}]    
[s for s in lst if len(s.intersection(x)) > len(x) * 0.6]
```

Comment: It would work faster if you assign `len(x) * 0.6` to a variable before the comprehension.